# PHP configure error

Tags: php, makefile, configure

I just installed the PDO_DBLIB extension. In short, I downloaded it from PECL, and ran the following commands:

```
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpize

./configure 

make
```

The extension installed successfully, but I forgot to run ./configure with the previously set options. So, I tried to re-running the configure command like so:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/zend --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/zend/etc
```

with 20 or so additional options that I didn't list for brevity's sake (pdo, mysql, etc). But this time, I get the following error when configuring PHP:

```
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
```

I've googled this error and can't find a solution. I also checked SO and I can't find an answer here either (questions that included this error were left unanswered). Can someone please, please help me figure this out? My development box is down until I can reconfigure PHP with the initial options :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the file config.h was already in the directory when I ran:

```
./configure
```

Deleting config.h resolved the issue.